# Horizontal overflow occuring with CSS3 3D transformations

Tags: 3d, css, scrollbar, overflow, transformation

I have a problem on http://mr.si/ with CSS3 3D transformation. I am doing it plainly for fun and exploring new CSS functions but it disturbs me.

The problem occurs when you hover over the last two items in a row. Additionally to wanted effect something unwanted happens - element overflows horizontally dramatically and horizontal scroll bar appears which is not pleasant at all.

Maybe its a WebKit bug but its occurring in the latest Chrome Developer build and in Safari 5 so probably it's not.

Any idea what I did wrong?

EDIT:
Worth noting that I changed the site so this is no longer relevant :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell you the truth your problem left me flabbergasted, it looks like a browser bug to me.

However, I found a simple fix:

```
#main section {
overflow: hidden;
// the rest of your css declarations
}
```

It's more of a patch than an insight of why it's doing weird stuff, but I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Edit: Solved it with....

```
header[role="banner"], #main, #main + footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  //yourcode
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but then this clipping occurs at both ends: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/88844/Screen%20shot%202010-12-02%20at%2021.37.48.PNG